# Moved my files - lost my progress

Tags: blend-files

I'm just starting out and tried Blender Guru's Donut Tutorial and I was almost finished.

Last night, I did a final render for the day and closed the project. I then realized that I hadn't created a subfolder for the project itself and everything was stored in \Blender\Projects. I wanted to tidy everything up a bit, so I moved the only 3 files I had (Donut.blend, Donut.blend1 & Dough.png (the texture file which is created during the tutorial) to a new Folder \Blender\Projects\Donut. (All the Files can be found here: [Google Drive with project files](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1i_gABeKQiRYpsM8cw3u_axje4vFlxI46?usp=sharing)

Today, I continued with the final parts of the tutorial without realizing something was not working properly. After spending hours today, I realized that rendering a new frame gave me a blank output with 0 seconds of render time. (see screenshot) [image: blank render]

After some trial and error I realized, that it was because I moved my files to a different location. moving them back to  \Blender\Projects gave me a render output again, but without all of today's progress.
Note that this only affects the rendered image, not the viewport which is identical in both instances, with all the changes I made today.

I've been switching back and forth, trying different combinations of the "External Files" Setting (embedding images, relative and absolute paths, finding missing files etc.) but nothing seems to bring my progress back into my rendered image. I should also note that it doesn't matter which render engine i choose.

What confuses me the most about this, is that it is possible to see everything as it should be in the viewport, only to lose A LOT of stuff when I hit render. (and yes, everything is set to be shown during rendering) Even the camera angle from the keyframe doesn't match from viewport to render!
I'd be really interested to understand how that is even possible.

[image: same frame, everything is checked to make visible in render]

Does anyone know of a method to fix this issue, or is all my progress lost forever?

Comment: providing your blend file would help...

Comment: sorry @chris, added it now!
[Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1i_gABeKQiRYpsM8cw3u_axje4vFlxI46?usp=sharing)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does my object not show up?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/67490/why-does-my-object-not-show-up)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your output properties: uncheck "Sequencer".

[image]

Then you can render:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! That did the trick :)

Comment: you are welcome. Glad i could help.